# regexp найти до точки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как найти выражение все маленькие буквы до точки или второе условие найти JPG большие. Собственно мне нужно переименновывать название с маленьких на большие буквы а разширение, если есть большие на маленькие. тоесть .JPG на .jpg и если namefile.jpg на NAMEFILE.jpg.

Comment: А на каком языке это надо делать то??

Comment: `/([a-z])\./` например, только точка попадет в полное совпадение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти последние 3 больший + точка можно так

```
\.[A-Z]{3}$
```

`\.` ищем символ точки, если тока ненужна в выборке то эту часть удаляем.
`[A-Z]` Ищем только большие буквы, `[]` говорит что мы ищем не конкретный символ ,а группу. `{3}` тут говорим что эта группа должна повторятся 3 раза, т.е. 3 символа. `$` тут говорим что ищем с конца.
А вообще можно зайти на сайт для онлайн тестов регулярок и поиграться самому, я например использую [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), там даже подсказки есть, правда на английском.